# How to apply two different animations to the same element with different duration?

Tags: jquery, html

I've already found a solution using **{queue: true}**, but the problem is that this doesn't seem to work in my case.

I've created a fiddle to help you understand my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/c6SS9/1/.

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(function() {
    for(var i=0; i < $('.block').size(); i++) {
        $('.block').eq(i).delay(i*200).animate({'left': '300px'}, 700);
        $('.block').eq(i).delay(i*200).animate({'opacity': '1'}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});
    }
});​
```

What i want is that the animation used for the **opacity** starts when the block start to move and this has to happen for each block.

Comment: can you not just increase the duration of the opacity animation?

Comment: But this is not really what I want. What I want is that the opacity animation start when each block starts to move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you understand the problem is that the `opacity` animation bypasses delay as it is not on the queue.

In this case, use the generic [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) function to add the animations AFTER the delay, so that they are executed after the delay even if they are not on the queue

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6SS9/2/)

Comment: Can you please tell which is in your opinion the best way to execute a function after the animation of the last block is completed?

Comment: If you ask me, I would use `complete` for the `opacity` animation

Comment: Yes but with {queue: false} in the opacity animation I can't  use a callback function. I've tryed and it's not working.

Comment: You can still use `complete` in the `options` object you pass to `.animate()`: http://jsfiddle.net/c6SS9/9/. The problem is you want to execute that for only the last block. You can add a class or id to the last block, or use `.index()` to check if it is the last block, if it is then execute the rest of the function.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought `complete` and `callback function` were the same thing, but they're not. Thank you again!!